# Splitting string by square brackets

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a string that comes out like this: 1.[Aagaard,Lindsay][SeniorPolicyAdvisor][TREASURYBOARDSECRETARIAT][DEPUTYPREMIERANDPRESIDENTOFTHETREASURYBOARD,Toronto][416-327-0948][lindsay.aagaard@ontario.ca]2.[Aalto,Margaret][ProbationOfficer][CHILDRENANDYOUTHSERVICES][THUNDERBAY,ThunderBay][807-475-1310][margaret.aalto@ontario.ca]

I want to split it into an arraylist like this:

1.

Aagaard,Lindsay

SeniorPolicyAdvisor

etc.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have a read of the String and Strings JavaDoc, see if that helps you out

Comment: Are the 1. 2. supposed to be captured as well?

Answer (score 3):

I read the JavaDoc and used Pattern and Matcher like so:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?)\\]");
Matcher m = p.matcher(tableContent);

while(m.find()) {
  System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First delete the first and the last brackets and then split by '][':

```
String arr = "[Aalto,Margaret][ProbationOfficer][CHILDRENANDYOUTHSERVICES]";
String[] items = arr.substring(1, arr.length() - 1).split("][");
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply this:

```
String[] list = str.split("\\[");

for(int i = 0 ; i < list.length ; i++) {
    list[i] = list[i].replace("\\]", "");
}
```

Comment: Why not split on `\]?\[`?

Comment: it throws an exception at at the split: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 0 @Maljam

Comment: @kknaguib then escape it: `str.split("\\[")`.

Comment: @Maljam `[` and `]` are used to construct regexs, which is used for `split`.